# How can you show data in a CDF Animate Graphic?

Tags: dynamic, manipulate, graphics3d

I want to show (dynamically) the curvature and torsion in a CDF to understand the quantitative measure of any points. Do you know what I have to do to show data in a `Animate` graph?
https://www.dropbox.com/s/85sy5bg9c96f818/Helice%20Pagina%2090%20OK%20TOTAL.cdf

I want to view curvature and torsion in different curves to understanding the graphical sense.

Thank you.

---

I add the code where i want to see dynamically the curvature and torsion

Hello, what i want if to visualize the curvatura and torsion in every point where you can see the Frenet-3 vectors

```
Clear[a]
r[t_] := {Sin[t], Cos[t], a*t}
uT[t_] := Simplify[r'[t]/Norm[r'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
vN[t_] := Simplify[uT'[t]/Norm[uT'[t]], t \[Element] Reals]
vB[t_] := 
 Simplify[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]/Norm[Cross[r'[t], r''[t]]], 
  t \[Element] Reals]
{uT[t], vN[t], vB[t]} // Column // TraditionalForm

rp1[t_] = Simplify[D[r[t], t]]
rp2[t_] = Simplify[D[rp1[t], t]]
rp3[t_] = Simplify[D[rp2[t], t]]

{rp1[t], rp2[t], rp3[t]} // Column // TraditionalForm

(*rr[t_]:=Simplify[r[t],t\[Element]Reals]
{rr[t]}//Column//TraditionalForm*)

curvatura[t_] := 
 Sqrt[Cross[rp1[t], rp2[t]].Cross[rp1[t], rp2[t]]]/(Sqrt[
     rp1[t].rp1[t]]^3)
Print["curv ", curvatura[t]]
Print["curv ", N[ curvatura[2]]]
Print["curv ", curvatura[Pi/2]]
Print["curv ", curvatura[Pi]]

torsion[t_] := 
 Det[{rp1[t], rp2[t], rp3[t]}]/
  Sqrt[Cross[rp1[t], rp2[t]].Cross[rp1[t], rp2[t]]]
Print["tors ", torsion[t]]
Print["tors ", N[torsion[2]]]
Print["tors ", torsion[Pi/2]]
Print["tors ", torsion[Pi]]

Simplify[Norm /@ {uT[t], vN[t], vB[t]}, t \[Element] Reals]
Manipulate[
 Show[ParametricPlot3D[{r[t]}, {t, -Pi/a, Pi/a}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}], 
  Graphics3D[{{Thick, Darker@Red, 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + uT[s]}]}, {Thick, Darker@Green, 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + vB[s]}]}, {Thick, Darker@Cyan, 
     Arrow[{r[s], r[s] + vN[s]}]}}],(*Print[curvatura[r,s]],Print[
  torsion[r,s]],*)PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}, {-Pi, Pi}}, 
  ViewPoint -> {3, -2, 2}], 
 Style["Representación espacial de la noria del hamster", 12, 
  Bold], Delimiter, {{a, 0.5, "a (elegir valor entre -1 y 1)"}, -1, 1,
   Appearance -> "Open"}, Delimiter, {{s, -Pi, 
   "Valor del parametro en el que se visualizar el Triedro de \
Frenet"}, -Pi/a, Pi/a, 
  Appearance -> 
   "Open"},(*Delimiter,Style["Curva Azul.- Representación de la \
curva" r[u],Darker@Blue],*)Style["Curvatura ", curvatura[s]], 
 Style["Torsión ", torsion[s]],
 Style["Vertor Rojo.- Representa el vector Tangente", Darker@Red], 
 Style["Vector Cyan.- Representa el vector Normal", Darker@Cyan], 
 Style["Vector Verde.- Representa el vector Binormal", Darker@Green], 
 ControlPlacement -> Left, SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

---

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Mathematica StackExchange. It is helpful to include a minimal, working example that illustrates the important part of the problem. Users can then copy/paste/try your code and reproduce your problem.  (There seems to be no code in your CDF.)

Comment: Related demonstration: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/CurvatureAndTorsion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a dynamic graph, some data about it.  There are many ways to organize and display information, so if this is not helpful, perhaps the question could be edited to be more specific about what output is desired.

```
a = 3.;
Row[{Slider[Dynamic@a, {1, 5}], Dynamic@Plot[Sin[a t], {t, 0 , 6}], 
  " Period ", Dynamic[ 2 \[Pi]/a], " "}]
```

[image: Slider, plot, period]

---

**Addendum**

For the curvature and torsion lines, you need something like

```
Row[{Style["Curvatura "], Dynamic@curvatura[s]}],
Row[{Style["Torsión "], Dynamic@torsion[s]}],
```

The `Style` wrapped around each string is unnecessary, unless you wish to change the style.
The default looks like this:

[image: OP's Manipulate with my mods]

Comment: Hello, what i want if to visualize the curvatura and torsion in every point where you can see the Frenet-3 vectors...... i tried with Row.... as you suggested me, but i can´t reach solution.

Here is the code. What and where i have to put the extra code to reach the solution.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/to27y9u8ua0552a/code_triedro.txt

THANK YOU very much.

Comment: Perfect Michael E2.

You have solve my question 100%

Comment: @MikaIke OK, you're welcome.

Comment: as extras.... ¿How can i put curvatura and torsion in bigger TrueType to see easy?

as a extra ;-) because you has solve plenty my question

Comment: @MikaIke  Use `Style`.  `Style[expr, Larger]` or `Style[expr, 16]`, where `expr` is what you want bigger.  It can be the whole `Row`.

Comment: Michael E2, THANK YOU VERY MUCH. 

Your answer is PERFECT!